# How to know from which website we were redirected to

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a back button on my application. When users come from another domain to mine. How can I know from which URL user landed on my application?

I would like to redirect the user to the URL they have come with when they click on my "Go back` button.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to replicate the browser's functionality as they already do that perfectly fine.

But if you really want to, you can just use [`history.back()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/history). And if you really really want to know where the user came from, you can use [`document.referrer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer).

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of ways for doing that
 1. By using document
    var prevURL = document.referrer;

2. by using Window
   window.history.back();